# XCode/Cocoa Development in Eclipse IDE on Mac

Tags: xcode

Is there any Plugin available in Eclipse (Mac) for XCode/Cocoa development? Is XCode Editor in Mac, the only option?

Regards,
Sandip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Apple has provided Xcode and I am not aware of any other third party (or Apple provided IDE). So AFAIK Xcode is the only option.

Comment: I think you didn't get the intent of the question, I asked whether any other IDE inside Mac for XCode Development

Comment: OK..Apologies for misunderstanding. But still Xcode is the only option AFAIK. Edited my answer.

Comment: It's not an Eclipse plugin, but there is another IDE available from JetBrains called AppCode - [http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/)